# How do I resize the border of the body as the window resizes in CSS

Tags: html, css, resize, border

I have a small, green border on the right, to add a little readability. If you shrink the window however, you can see it just ends up covering everything. It looks equally absurd on a mobile device screen too. How do I make it so it resizes?

```
body {
  color: #325050;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  border-right: 50em solid;
}
```

Comment: your  `border-right: 50em solid` is making the problem. Please explain better to help you

Comment: Hey, I understand your problem. You have to develop a responsive web to achieve that. You can use Twitter Bootstrap Framework for that.
But just try once setting the viewport. Add this line in your head tag. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
body {
  color: #325050;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  border-right: 50vw solid; /* changed*/
}
```

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height

These measurements give you a nice way to define width and height of things like border in percentages.

For sizing things relative to the current viewport size  you can find out more [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: perfect! never thought it'd be so easy. this doesn't seem to apply to mobile screens though. i'm guessing another approach is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be responsive to both width and height changes, you can use:

```
body {
  border: min(30vh, 20vw) solid;
}
```